# Como buscar uma informação em duas tabelas diferentes e retornar o ID da tabela onde a informação está?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho um código que pode ser de pessoa física **OU** jurídica, e tenho uma tabela para cada um (uma para PF e outra para PJ).

Gostaria de encontrar esse usuário em uma das duas tabelas e retornar suas informações.

Ressalto que ele (usuário) só vai estar presente em uma das duas...

Estou fazendo dessa forma no momento:

```
select *
user.ID     as UserID
,conta.Email    as Email
,pf.Nome    as NomeUser
,pf.ID      as IDUser
from Users user
inner join PFContas pfconta on pfconta.PFID = user.PFID
inner join PF pf on pf.ID = pfconta.PFID
inner join Contas conta on conta.Id = pfcc.ContaID
where
conta.ID = '579'
```

Mas esse só se aplica para PF, como faria com que a mesma query buscasse na tabela de PJ, caso não encontrasse nessa?

Comment: Está meio confuso. O que vem a ser pfcc? Pode existir como PF e PJ ou apenas como um dos dois? Avaliou se UNION não te atende?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Está meio confuso. O que vem a ser pfcc? Pode existir como PF e PJ ou
>   apenas como um dos dois? Avaliou se UNION não te atende?

Esse comentário dá a solução para a situação, devido a forma como as tabelas estão criadas, precisei usar um `union all` entre uma query voltada para as informações de Pessoa Física e outra voltada para Pessoa Jurídica.

Answer (score 2):

Utilize `LEFT JOIN` ao invés de `INNER JOIN` nas tabelas desejadas, sendo assim, trará sempre contendo numa ou na outra tabela.

De uma olhada melhor [aqui](https://www.devmedia.com.br/clausulas-inner-join-left-join-e-right-join-no-sql-server/18930)

Comment: Na verdade não resolveu, mas eu encontrei um outro jeito, de qualquer forma, agradeço!